# Why in forward bending knee orientation in quadruped legged robot require less torque in knee joint?

Tags: mobile-robot, dynamics, mechanism

I'm trying to find answer in terms of physics explanation, why knee joint torque requirement is less in the forward bending leg orientation of a quadruped legged robot.
I'm referring this article, in the paragraph 2.2. (Table 1 & 2)---
https://nereus.mech.ntua.gr/Documents/pdf_ps/eccomas15-2.pdf

Thank you in advance. Any answer or comment or upvote will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward bent knees require less torque for these use cases because of the configuration. With the forward bent knee the force vector from the point of contact goes much closer to the knee joint resulting in a much lower moment arm. This lower moment arm means that the torque is much lower for a given force.

The other simple way to think about this is that in the forward knee position when pushing forward and upward, the lower limb is much more under compression rather than needing to be twisted to provide the force at the foot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DibyasankhaKundu please accept the answer so others know that your question has an answer when they search.